# C program to clear nth bit of a number using bitwise and operator

Tags: bit-manipulation, highest

I don't understand why these are different
this is how I wrote it :

```c
 number &= 0 << time;
```

and this is how it should be written :

```c
number &= ~(1 << time);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitwise operations are performed on all bits.

The result of `0 << time` is *time*th bit set to zero, and all other bits are zero. So all bits are zero. Bitwise and with zero will always result in zero.

Contrary, the result of `1 << time` is *time*th bit set to one, and all other bits are zero. After bitwise negation, the result is *time*th bit set to zero, and all other bits are one. Bitwise and will zero out only *time*th bit.